# Error when saving @Lob with hibernate java mysql

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Technology:

hibernate 4.3.4.Final

spring-data-jpa 1.5.0.RELEASE

mysql-connector-java 5.1.30

c3p0 0.9.5-pre8

Some part of dao context:

```
<bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close"
    class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass"
        value="${MyApp_Persistance.connection.driver_class}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${MyApp_Persistance.connection.url}" />
    <property name="user" value="${MyApp_Persistance.connection.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${MyApp_Persistance.connection.password}" />
</bean>
```

I have entity OrganizationDetail:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "OrganizationDetails")
public class OrganizationDetail implements Serializable {
...
...
...

    @Lob
    private String address;

...
```

and when im trying to save entity into database i get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Method com/mchange/v2/c3p0/impl/NewProxyPreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(ILjava/io/Reader;J)V is abstract
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.setCharacterStream(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.ClobTypeDescriptor$4$1.doBind(ClobTypeDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2843)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3248)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3183)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3525)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:158)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:461)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:347)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:513)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor$LockModePopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(LockModeRepositoryPostProcessor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy55.save(Unknown Source)
    at hr.myapp.service.impl.OrganizationServiceImpl.save(OrganizationServiceImpl.java:50)
    at hr.myapp.web.bean.OrganizationBean.saveOrganizationAction(OrganizationBean.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 76 more
```

Can anyone point me to right direction ? Is there any jar missing ?
I'm sure that this error pops up when i use @Lob annotation!

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.javathinking.com/2013/04/photo-credit-markchadwickart-via.html It seems that c3p0 version 0.9.2.1 doesn't have this problem. Your c3p0 version (0.9.5-pre8) seems unstable. Maybe you should downgrade your c3p0 version to 0.9.2.1 (or to another stable version) and give it a try.

Comment: Hello. Wow thanks. Will let you know if this will resolve my issue today later after i try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same problem with Java, Hibernate, Oracle 11g and @Lob annotation.

Searching on web i found that it is fixed by upgrading C3P0 to stable version 0.9.2.1.

Link to MVN Repository, useful if you are using Maven: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0/0.9.2.1

If not using Maven just download from Sourceforge C3PO site:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/c3p0/files/c3p0-bin/c3p0-0.9.2.1/

That worked for me.

Comment: Yes, that was solution for my problem. I updated C3P0 to stable version 0.9.2.1.